# RFID+Fingerprint sensor code

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors, rfid

I'm trying to create a security door system that uses an RFID and fingerprint sensor (Adafruit) to allow/deny access to a door. I have the fingerprint sensor and RFID hooked up to an LED, but the code isn't working very well. I want the LED to light only and only when both fingerprints and RFID are verified. Here is my preliminary code.

```
//HEADERFILES
#include <SPI.h> //rfid 
#include <MFRC522.h>//rfid 
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h> //FINGERPRINT
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //FINGERPRINT
#include<stdint.h> //FINGERPRINT

//rfid settings
#define RST_PIN         9          // rfid pin 9 RST_pin
#define SS_PIN          10         // rfid pin 10 SS_pin
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance
String read_rfid;
String ok_rfid_1 = "cbb427b2"; //white card
String ok_rfid_2 = "0ebb14f39"; //blue key chain

//fingerprint settings
int getFingerprintIDez();
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (YELLOW wire)
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
//activates serial communication on pin 2 & 3
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

//output garage door pin
int door = 7; //motor to door

void dump_byte_array(byte * buffer , byte bufferSize) { //why so important
  read_rfid = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    read_rfid = read_rfid + String(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}

void setup() {
  //RFID setup
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  while (!Serial);
  // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  finger.begin(57600);
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 RFID
  pinMode (door, OUTPUT);
  //FINGERPRINT setup
  {
    while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
    if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
      Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
      while (1);
    }
    Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
  }

}

// OK success!

p = finger.image2Tz();
switch (p) {
case FINGERPRINT_OK:
  Serial.println("Image converted");
  break;
case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
  Serial.println("Image too messy");
  return p;
case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
  Serial.println("Communication error");
  return p;
case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
  Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
  return p;
case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
  Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
  return p;
default:
  Serial.println("Unknown error");
  return p;
}
}



//DOOR/OUTPUT PIN PROPERTIES CHANGE TO REFLECT HOW FAST AND HOW LONG MOTOR     PULLS DOOR USING DIGITALWRITE; BREAK..   //USING LED FOR NOW

void open_door() {
  digitalWrite (door, HIGH);
  delay (2000);
  digitalWrite (door, LOW);
}


void loop() {
  // RFID LOOP SETTINGS                                                   `
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {     // Look for new cards
    return;
  }
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {       // Select one of the c ards
    return;
  }
  dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
  Serial.println(read_rfid);
  // FINGERPRINT LOOP SETTINGS

  getFingerprintID();  // start fingerprint sensor
  delay(100);

  uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
    uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
      case FINGERPRINT_OK:
        Serial.println("Image taken");
        break;
      case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
        Serial.println("No finger detected");
        return p;
      case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
        Serial.println("Communication error");
        return p;
      case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
        Serial.println("Imaging error");
        return p;
      default:
        Serial.println("Unknown error");
        return p;
    }

    p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
    if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK && read_rfid == ok_rfid_1) {
      Serial.println(ok_rfid_1);
      open_door();
    }

  }
```

**And this is the error I am getting**

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

fingerprint:127: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

 {

 ^

exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before '{' token

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I am new to this so please bear with me and explain in childish manner if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Please take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour.    And btw, when you put in code, just make sure you have one blank line at the top then enter the code with 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.  It is much more readable that way.

Comment: Looks like your switch statement is outside a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I have read what you posted here or what you're trying to do, however nonetheless I have fixed the errors in your post. This will compile no problem. Good luck with your project.

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int getFingerprintIDez();
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

//HEADERFILES
#include <SPI.h> //rfid 
#include <MFRC522.h>//rfid 
#include<stdint.h> //FINGERPRINT

//RFID settings
#define RST_PIN         9          // RFID pin 9 RST_pin
#define SS_PIN          10         // RFID pin 10 SS_pin
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance
String read_rfid;
String ok_rfid_1 = "cbb427b2"; //white card
String ok_rfid_2 = "0ebb14f39"; //blue key chain

int door = 7; //motor to door

void dump_byte_array(byte * buffer , byte bufferSize) {
  //why so important
  read_rfid = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    read_rfid = read_rfid + String(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}

void setup() {
  //RFID setup
  finger.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  while (!Serial);
  // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 RFID
  pinMode (door, OUTPUT);
  //FINGERPRINT setup
  {
    while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
    if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
      Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
      while (1);
    }
    Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
  }
}

// OK success!

void open_door() {
  digitalWrite (door, HIGH);
  delay (2000);
  digitalWrite (door, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // RFID LOOP SETTINGS
  if (! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    // Look for new cards
    return;
  }
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    // Select one of the cards
    return;
  }
  dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
  Serial.println(read_rfid);
  // FINGERPRINT LOOP SETTINGS
  getFingerprintID();  // start fingerprint sensor
  delay(100);
}

uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK success!
  p = finger.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
    Serial.println("Did not find a match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }
  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID);
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
default:
  Serial.println("Unknown error");
  return p;
}
} <-- Why?
```

Proper indentation shows that you have an extraneous closing curly brace.